# Rtos ( when using semaphore or mutex with lcd it run task with low priority first?)

Tags: embedded, rtos, lcd

This code for display on LCD according to which keep semaphore, it should begin from task with high priority, but it begin with task with low priority
if I delete the semaphore, it will begin with high priority.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "lcd.h"
#include "macros.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "semphr.h"

#define F_CPU 16000000
#include <util/delay.h>

/*task function prototype */
void TASK1(void * pvParameters );
void TASK2(void * pvParameters );
//void TASK3(void * pvParameters );



/*create a semaphore handle*/
//xSemaphoreHandle task_sync_sem ;
xSemaphoreHandle Semaphore1;

int main(void)
{
    DDRD=0xff;
    DDRB=0xff;
    /*init LCD*/
    LCD_init();


    //task_sync_sem = xSemaphoreCreateCounting(1,0);
    Semaphore1=xSemaphoreCreateCounting(1,1);
    /*create task */
    xTaskCreate(TASK1,"task1",400,NULL,8,NULL);
    xTaskCreate(TASK2,"task2",400,NULL,6,NULL);
    //xTaskCreate(TASK3,"task3",400,NULL,3,NULL);


    /*Start OS "Scheduler " */

    vTaskStartScheduler();


}

void TASK1(void * pvParameters )
{

    for (;;)
    {
      LCD_Clear();
    u8 vale=xSemaphoreTake(Semaphore1,50);
    if(vale==1)
    {
        LCD_WriteData('A');
        LCD_WriteData('B');
        LCD_WriteData('C');
        xSemaphoreGive(Semaphore1);

    }
            _delay_ms(1000);
            vTaskDelay(2000);

    }

}
void TASK2(void * pvParameters )
{

    for (;;)
    {
          LCD_Clear();


        u8 vale=xSemaphoreTake(Semaphore1,50);

            if(vale==1)
            {
                LCD_WriteData('X');
                LCD_WriteData('Y');
                LCD_WriteData('Z');
                xSemaphoreGive(Semaphore1);
                vTaskDelay(2000);
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Be explicit in your question about which task runs when using the task _names_ it seems clear to me that task2 will run until the semaphore take, when task1 will run until the semaphore give.  task1 will output first because of the position of the take in task2.

Comment: Ok, not so clear perhaps.  The FreeRTOS documentation is not explicit but since `tskIDLE_PRIORITY == 0` it seems that low numbered priorities are lower priority - that is not the case for all (or even most)  RTOS, where zero is high.  More information required - show the actual output rather then _describing_ it.  And fix the question in the manner I described - edit, do not add a comment (or even an answer as you did previously).

Answer (score 0):

- Check your **configMAX_PRIORITIES** is higher or equal to 8 (your maximum priority).
  [Task Priorities](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-priority.html)
- For your case, a Mutex seems more appropriate [Mutex](http://www.freertos.org/CreateMutex.html)
- You should also include the LCD_Clear() within the semaphore lock.

---

### Behavior:

Your problem is probably related to the fact you create a counting semaphore with a maximum value of 1 and a starting value of 1, so it is already "Taken".

```
Semaphore1=xSemaphoreCreateCounting(1,1);
```

My guess, when your Task 1 execute, it is not able to take the semaphore and thus wait for 50 tick, in which the Task 2 will execute, but should also fail to take the semaphore as it is never "given" since it was locked from the begining.

Try to initialize with  `Semaphore1=xSemaphoreCreateCounting(1,0);` , or better, use a mutex.